How to set root (/ and /de) as homepage in 2 menus?
While configuring other things I noticed that homepage is set to a "Featured articles" page in an invisible menu.
Now I'm considering adding it to 2 visible menus in 2 languages. I'm not too sure what the best approach for this would be as setting "Featured articles" as homepage is extremely weird compared to e.g. Wordpress in the 1st place.
Do I move the "Featured articles" entry to the displayed menu in 1 language, then add URL /de entry to the German one? Or is there an better practice for this in Joomla 4 I'm missing?

The Category Blog view lists all articles from a specified category with intro image and intro text + "read more" button. The Featured Articles uses a similar layout but instead it lists all articles from different categories that are marked "featured".
I usually create one Featured Articles menu item per language that I set as homepage for that language. Because the articles are assigned to a language, only the article marked as "featured" from the current language are shown by the Featured Articles view.
The "hidden menu" technique is no longer necessary because you can "hide" individual menu items. I usually "hide" the home page menu item (in menu item > Link Type > Display in Menu: No) because I already link the site logo to the homepage.

The confusion here came from the fact that Joomla requires you to set the global homepage even though you already have language-based homepages, which display as flags and I didn't realize what that means.
In case anyone encounters a similar problem and you don't know what to set as global homepage, you need to:

create a menu that isn't displayed anywhere. Or even better one per language as it turns out that Joomla also requires you to set layout for certain pages through menu entries... See e.g. Change Smart Search results template layout
place some random item in there, with alias that won't be viewed by anyone and that you'll block in robots.txt

Then you can work on homepage per language as this answer specifies.
